# Why am I getting problem in assigning fetched data from API to setState in React?

Tags: reactjs

In this piece of code, I am successfully retrieving data from my API. Now my problem is I am unable to assign the fetched values to my state values. Please help me :)

Here is my API call to backend which is working fine -

```
export const getData = (id) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/course`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(id),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("error in hitting route"));
};
```

here is my react component which runs well :

```
  export default function App() {

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "", 
    description: "", 
    price: "", 
    error: "", 
  });

  const preload = (id) => {
    getData(id).then((data) => {
      if(data.error) {
        setValues({...values, error: data.error});
      }
      else {
        console.log("this is fetched data ", data); // I am successfully receiving this data!
        setValues({
          ...values,
          name: data.name,
          description: data.description, 
          price: data.price,
          error: false
        });

        console.log(values); // I am getting everything empty here e.g. name: "", description: "", price: ""
        // I am unable to understand why it is not assigning fetched data to my state.

      }
    })

  }


  useEffect(() => {
    preload(match.params.id);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Please use values fetched here.</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```